# Monitors don't work when plugged into motherboard

Tags: motherboard

Whenever I plug a monitor into ther graphics output on my motherboard it doesn't have a signal, but when I plug a monitor into my dedecated graphics card it works.

Any reasons on why that's happening?

Comment: Yes, the motherboard disables its video output because you have a graphics card. Sometimes you can change this in the BIOS. Other times it is not supported to have onboard video active at the same time as an add-on video card.

Comment: Further,  you can usually remove the GPU and then the onboard will work. And like @Appleoddity said, their usually is a way to set using both in the BIOS although I think the dedicated GPU is still typically the primary.

Comment: I see where I could change it in the BIOS, but it only lets me choose pci-e slot 1,2 or the motherboard. However I had this same motherboard a month ago(before I had to buy a new one, still the same model though) and it worked.

Comment: I've found that if the change happens by the mere insertion of the display adapter then it is likely the motherboard won't support both.  But you can always try.  Meanwhile, can we have some more information, such as the brand/model of the PC?  That can help attract useful answers.

Answer (score -1):

Whenever I bought the new motherboard, Internal graphics was disabled. All I had to do was enable it in the bios and the other monitors were working.

Thank you for your help @SDsolar @Damon and @Appleoddity!